# Uses of "within": what does "within x days of a determined date" mean?

Tags: meaning

The segment of the text goes like this:
"[...]the predicted calving date was within 0.9 days of the actual calving date when ultrasound was undertaken [...]"

I have to translate this and I can't figure if the predicted (via ultrasound) date happened 0,9 days earlier or later than the actual date.

Comment: This question sounds similar to a lot of previous questions we've had on the meaning of "within x days," except that this one appears to be asking about _within_ in the sense of "plus or minus x days [from a reference point date]" rather than "before the expiration of x days." so I think it may not be a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You can't tell if the prediction was early or late. It's a measure of overall accuracy, ±0.9 days.

```
Early                    Late
----+----+----+----+----+----
   -1         0         1
     └─────────────────┘
```

The prediction was within the bracketed range.

Comment: Ahh. That actually makes things easier. Thank you!