# Is "of" the same as "following"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

If you say something must occur within one year "of" something else, does the use of the word "of" mean the thing can occur within one year before or following something else? Or is "of" the same as "following"

Comment: Specific context needed. The words can be used in many different contexts, with different meanings.  For instance "five minutes of 3" means five minutes BEFORE 3 o'clock.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uses of "within": what does "within x days of a determined date" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349837/uses-of-within-what-does-within-x-days-of-a-determined-date-mean)